# Where does SQL Server store the stored procedure code?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I once needed the lines of the stored procedures to be able to trace whether I have a reference to some function, procedure or table, or sometimes to try to find something inside of the sp's code.

Where does SQL Server store the procedure's code?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `sys.sql_modules` because `definition` is `nvarchar(max)` because it will not truncate long code.

In `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` the `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` column is only `nvarchar(4000)` so if you try view the text of a long procedure and you will see that it is truncated.

Use this to search for text in any procedure, view, function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition Like '%'+@Search+'%'
    ORDER BY o.type_desc,o.name
```

use this to view the text of a given procedure, view, function:

```
select * from sys.sql_modules where object_id=object_id('YourProcedure')
```

Comment: sys.sql_modules seems to be nearly unknown. it is the true sql05+ solution, rather than infoschema and syscomments

Comment: @devio, it is in BOL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx, so I'm not sure why no one knows about it.  If you want the full definition, then it is `THE` solution.

Comment: why you used DISTINCT clause, can there be multiple rows for any object ?

Comment: @zia, this query doesn't return any schema info, there could be many different schemas with the same object in each

Comment: I used to think that `syscomments` was just as good, but I now realise it can give false positives when used with a `NOT LIKE` search, due to the proc being split across several rows.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
select object_definition(object_id(routine_name)) from information_schema.routines
```

or

```
select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects where name = 'foo'
```

or even

```
select object_definition(object_id('foo')); -- 'foo' is the table name
```

These versions are never truncated.

Answer (score 3):

It stored it inside the system schema tables:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

See MSDN about the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` view:

```
ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v10/MS.SQLSVR.v10.en/s10de_6tsql/html/c75561b2-c9a1-48a1-9afa-a5896b6454cf.htm
```

For a content search on this, you can do the follwing:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%search_string%'
```

Comment: in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES ROUTINE_DEFINITION is only nvarchar(4000) so try view the text of a long procedure and you will see it is truncated.  See my answer for how to get the complete code of long procedures.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to view the stored procedures code you go into the progammabiltity folder within your DB and they should be all stored in there under stored procedures.

Comment: Not an easy way to search the contents though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to search for references to other objects, then you can run a query like this:

SELECT *
FROM syscomments
WHERE TEXT LIKE '%searchstring%'

This will return any objects in the database that reference the search string. You can then look at these objects to see what stored procedures (and views and functions) are doing so.

Comment: syscomments.text is nvarchar(4000) and as a result will truncate anything that is longer.  See my answer for a system view that uses a nvarchar(max) column and as a result, will not truncate

Comment: it doesn't actually truncate, it just creates multiple rows for any procedures that get too long. It is definitely harder to use if you have stored procedures that are that long, and the view you made reference to is definitely a better solution. Of course, if you are creating individual procedures that are 4000+ characters long, maybe you deserve to be forced to do things that are more difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

**View Dependencies**

In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on a table, and choose "View Dependencies". You will see every object that references the table

**INFORMATION_SCHEMA**

The actual code for a stored proc, view, constraint, etc is stored in `SysComments`. You should query this using the views provided in the schema `Information_Schema`. Here are all the components of the [Information_Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server Management Studion, you can right click on the database you want, then click "Tasks -> Generate Scripts".

There you can generate a script with all the SP's in one single file, separated files, or directly to a query window, and search/change what you want.

Hope this helps.

(this is for SQL Server 2008, but i think 2005 has this functionality too)

EDIT:

You can also see one single SP code, by following this path "YourDB -> Programmability -> Stored Procedures", then right click on the SP you want to see, and click "Modify", and a query window is opened with the code.