# Where is my all procedures, etc. from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I guess this or similar question was asked, but can not find one such.

Where are stored on my computer (automatically if you do not specify otherwise) all procedures and scripts that I wrote?

And if I am doing a new installation on the computer what the simplest and safest recover for everything?

Thanks

Comment: They are stored wherever you saved them. For procedures it will be whatever database you created them in. For scripts how would we know?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454537/where-does-sql-server-store-the-stored-procedure-code

Answer (score 0):

If you saved any files in SQL Server Management Studio and used default path then your saved scripts are in "`C:\Users\**YourWindowsLoginName**\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\`"

If you created your stored procedures in a database you have to remember in which database you've created these them and on which server.

If you did it on another server, they might be still there, you just have to ask somebody, who knows more about SQL Server on how to connect to that server and how to get access to the database you've used.

If you used SQL Server on your local PC, then Database files might also be still there. Search your Drive `C:\` for files with extension "`.mdf`" and "`.ldf`".
Most probably they are stored in the default location: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"` - That location for SQL 2014, but it might give you an idea where to search for.

PLEASE keep us posted if you find these Stored procedures, everybody have to know where to search it next time if anybody lost them. Help everybody else as I help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. in the first place i didnt found a file from the last 3 month except one of 'Visual Studio Setting File' type. i found in the other place. thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQL Server Management Studio will save queries to "C:\Users(windows log in username)\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio" and they should be saved as .sql

This is by default even with a new installation. So if you upgrade, or uninstall and/or reinstall a new version the folder and the scripts should still be there. I did this when I uninstalled SSMS and reinstalled to another drive on my machine.