# how to get full text format store procedure (full code) from information_schema.routines or Sys.sql_modules

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to get full text format store procedure (full code) from information_schema.routines or Sys.sql_modules 
using script:--

```
select top 1 cast(ROUTINE_DEFINITION  as TEXT)
FROM information_schema.routines
where ROUTINE_NAME like '%XXXXXXX%'
```

and

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Sys.sql_modules 
WHERE   definition LIKE '%XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%'
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specifics there...)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.ROUTINE_DEFINITION` view column is defined as `nvarchar(4000)` so no more than 4000 characters will be returned. Use `sys.sql_module.definition` to return the definition as `nvarchar(MAX)`. Don't use the deprecated `text` data type.

Note that SSMS may truncate the value according to the Query->Options-->Results setting.

Answer (score 1):

As found here:

[Where does SQL Server store the stored procedure code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454537/where-does-sql-server-store-the-stored-procedure-code)

this SQL will work without truncating the result:

```
select object_definition(object_id(routine_name)) from information_schema.routines
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope It helps you

```
SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME
        ,CAST(ROUTINE_DEFINITION AS NVARCHAR(MAX))As ROUTINE_DEFINITION
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE IN (
            'PROCEDURE'
            ,'FUNCTION'
            )
        AND ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%Your search string%'
    ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using SSMS in Azure Synapse Scalar Functions(FN) , Inline Functions(IF), Procedures(P) and Views(V)

1. using the query below in SSMS CNTL-D (Query Results to Grid)
2. copy results to a new query.
3. select a tilde character, ~ with `\n` (newline), CNTL-H (Replace)
4. with the find/replace popup focused use "replace using REGX", ALT+E
5. Replace All, ALT+A

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('IF OBJECT_ID(''',ss.[name],'.',o.[name],''',''IF'') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION ',ss.[name],'.',o.[name],';~'
--,replace(replace(replace(sm.[definition],CHAR(13), '~'),CHAR(10), '~'),'~~','~'),'~GO~')
FROM sys.objects AS o 
JOIN sys.sql_modules AS sm
    ON o.object_id = sm.object_id  
JOIN sys.schemas AS ss
    ON o.schema_id = ss.schema_id  
WHERE 1=1
--AND o.type = 'IF'
```